# heap overflow vs. return into libc

Tags: security, stack-overflow, exploit, shellcode, heap-corruption

I am attempting to educate myself on security, specifically vulnerabilities and exploits. I am currently reading the Shellcoders' Handbook and have the following question:
I know return-into-libc is a measure against having the NX bit set, and if I can use a return-into-libc attack, why would I want to use a heap overflow? Is there some situation where a heap overflow is preferable to return-into-libc?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two things here, the vulnerability or crash condition which leads to the process being in a state where an attacker can exploit it and the process hijacking technique  the attacker uses to execute their payload (exploit). Heap overflow is a vulnerability and return to libc is a hijack technique. Ie, you cannot use return to libc unless there is a vulnerability.